# What are the main differences between logstash and apache storm/spark streaming?

Tags: logstash, apache-storm, spark-streaming

I am searching a distributed real-time computing system that will collect data from a kafka server in order to process the data and then to store it in ElasticSearch. I already selected some of them:

- Apache Storm
- Apache Spark Streaming
- and Logstash (which is more descripted as an ETL (Extract, Transform, load))

I already found several tutorials comparing Storm and Spark Streaming. However, I did not find any tutorial comparing logstash to storm and spark streaming. This is very confusing for me because I am already familiar with logstash but I want to be sure that I select the right tool for my needs.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logstash is a data collection engine with real-time capabilities. It supports analysis, archiving, monitoring, alerting..based on some pre-defined  metrics.
--> Logstash is a kind of specific product, solution
Apache Spark and Storm are very general distributed real-time computation systems.
--> Apache Spark/Storm are just frameworks/libraries for general purposes.

Comment: ok thanks. In what use cases logstash may not be sufficent enough compared to storm and spark streaming ? Furthermore, does it give a better advance in terms of performances to be distributed ?

Comment: i just need to understand why some companies like Twitter use storm or spark streaming and not logstash. To me, it seems they do the same thing..

Comment: Let's see definition on the github: https://github.com/elastic/logstash . "Logstash is a tool for managing events and logs. You can use it to collect logs, parse them, and store them for later use (like, for searching). If you store them in Elasticsearch, you can view and analyze them with Kibana.

Comment: Storm and Spark are general frameworks, they can be used to achieve the same functionalities like LogStash if needed. Beside, they can be used to do a lot of different things. Some use cases I think not suitable for Logstash like: real-time distributed data processing and analytics..